# Biblioteca volley para android no se espera a la respuesta del servidor

Tags: android

Soy nuevo programando en Android y estoy tratando de crear una aplicación sencilla para hacer una cosulta GET a mi servidor y que me devuelva una cadena de texto de apenas 3 o 4 caracteres.

Para ello utilizo la biblioteca Volley que según dicen es muy sencilla de utilizar.

Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

Creo una cadena de texto: url = "http://miservidor.com/fichero.php?key=1234"
y lo mando vía volley con el siguiente código:

```
public String hacerGet(String url) {        

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.

    scode = null; //scode es un String definido en la cabecera

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response == "") scode = "Sin respuesta";
                    else scode = response;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //scode = "Error";
            //errServidor = error.getMessage();
            scode = error.getMessage();
        }

    });

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)); 
    queue.add(stringRequest);


    return scode;
}
```

El código funciona bien, hace la petición correctamente.

Ahora bien, el problema: se supone que la línea stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(...) hace que se espere 5s para recibir respuesta del servidor. Pues no funciona. Siempre devuelve scode = null. El codigo que llama a esta función hacerGet(url) lo tengo en un botón. Pulso el botón y en unas décimas de segundo tengo la respuesta de Null, cuando se supone que debería esperar 5s a que el servidor mío responda.

No sé qué hacer, ¿alguna ayuda?

Un saludo al foro.

Answer (score 1):

El código que estás usando es asíncrono :

// Request a string response from the provided URL.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //LA RESPUESTA LA OBTIENES AQUI
                if (response == "") scode = "Sin respuesta";
                else scode = response;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //AQUI SI ES QUE HAY ERROR
        //scode = "Error";
        //errServidor = error.getMessage();
        scode = error.getMessage();
    }

});

// AQUI NO OBTENDRAS LA RESPUESTA, ASI QUE NO PUEDES RETORNAR NADA
```

Podrías usar interfaces para solucionar tu problema, en el cual tu interface respondería dentro de onResponse.

Por último si de todas maneras quieres seguir haciéndolo con StringRequest y de forma sincrona, prueba con esto:

```
final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
final Object[] responseHolder = new Object[1];

final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        responseHolder[0] = response;
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        responseHolder[0] = error;
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
});
queue.add(stringRequest);
try {
    countDownLatch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
if (responseHolder[0] instanceof VolleyError) {
    final VolleyError volleyError = (VolleyError) responseHolder[0];
    scode = volleyError.getMessage();
} else {
    final String response = (String) responseHolder[0];
    if (response == "") scode = "Sin respuesta";
                    else scode = response;
}
```

**UPDATE (USANDO INTERFACE)**

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private TextView lblMensajes;
            private Button btnGet;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                //textview para ver los mensajes
                final TextView lblMensajes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMensajes);

                //botón
                final Button btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGet);

                //imageview para mostrar un punto verde o rojo según la respuesta del servidor
                final ImageView ivOk = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivOk);


                ivOk.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //no muestro imagen


                btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        int icanal = 0;


                            String url = hazYManda(icanal);

                            hacerGet(url, new DataResponseListener(){

                                 @Override
                                 public void onResponseData(String codigo){
                                                                         //tratamiento codigo recibido
                                        if (codigo == null) {//si el código recibido es null

                                            //imagen de un triangulo amarillo
                                            ivOk.setImageResource(R.drawable.alert);
                                            //muestro la imagen
                                            ivOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                            lblMensajes.setText("Sin respuesta del servidor\nIntentelo de nuevo");
                                        } else {
                                            //si recibo <0> es que ha ido todo bien
                                            if (codigo.contains("<0>")){
                                                ivOk.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
                                                lblMensajes.setText("Todo correcto");
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                //si no es <0> ha habido alguna incidencia
                                                //imagen de un punto rojo
                                                ivOk.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel);
                                                lblMensajes.setText("Ha habido alguna incidencia");
                                            }

                                            ivOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                        

                                        }

                                 }

                             }); 


                            //me espero 5 segundos para que no se pulse el botón rápidamente (desactivo el botón durante 5 s)
                            final long esperaTime = 5000L; //se espera 5s
                            btnGet.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    lblMensajes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099CC"));
                                    lblMensajes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                                    btnGet.setEnabled(true);
                                    lblMensajes.setText("Pulsa el botón");

                                    //ivNo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    ivOk.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    //ivAlerta.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            }, esperaTime);

                        }           


                    }
                });




            }


            public String hazYManda(int ipu) {
                //Esta función construye una cadena y con ella hace un GET a mi servidor.

                //Este es un ejemplo simplificado. Con la cadena recibida vía GET, el servidor
                //hace unas cuantas consultas a una base de datos MySQL y según el resultado de esas consultas
                //devuelve una cadena que es "<0>" si va todo bien o, en caso contrario, <1> o <2> según la incidencia

                //construyo la cadena ABCD:1
                String scadena = "ABCD:";
                scadena += Integer.toString(ipu);

                //construyo la cadena para hacer GET
                String xurl = "http://miservidor/fichero.php?key=" + scadena;


                return xurl;

            }




            public void hacerGet(String url, final DataResponseListener mListener) {

                scode = null;
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

                // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                if (response == "") scode = "Sin respuesta";
                                else scode = response;
                                if (mListener != null){
                                    mListener.onResponseData(scode);
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //scode = "Error";
                        //errServidor = error.getMessage();
                        scode = error.getMessage();
                        if (mListener != null){
                                    mListener.onResponseData(scode);
                                }
                    }

                });

                queue.add(stringRequest);
            }


            public interface DataResponseListener {
                void onResponseData(String data);
            }




        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, diegoveloper. Pruebo el código y comento.

Comment: Vaya, el código funciona, porque envía la petición, pero no recibe respuesta y la app se queda congelada. Lo he puesto en depuración y se queda atascada en la linea countDownLatch.await()...

Comment: Es porque necesitas realizar la petición en el background thread, ya que no puedes realizar operaciones pesadas en el main thread

Comment: La verdad es que no sé cómo hacer eso, estoy empezando en esto de Android. Sin embargo, investigando un poco, he leído aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675072/volley-and-asynctask que Volley ya se encarga de manejar los threads y no hay que hacerlo a mano. Si puedes pasarme algún código de ejemplo o ponerme algún enlace que me aclare las cosas, te lo agradecería.. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: ok te ayudo , lo puedes hacer de forma asincrona, pero necesito más info,  puedes actualizar tu pregunta y poner la clase que llama a  : String hacerGet(String url)

Comment: código actualizado usando interfaces, avisame si funciona :)

Comment: Mismo problema, recibe siempre null. He añadido al código la linea stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(55000, 1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)); delante de queue.add(... pero ni aún así. ¿No hay alguna forma de hacer un sleep() o algo así en el mListener (dicho desde la ignorancia)?

Comment: espera, cometí un error en mi código, estoy actualizandolo

Comment: public void onResponseData(String codigo){  <--- ese valor es el que debes usar para mostrar el código, actualizalo, antes estaba con "data"

Comment: si es que eso no te funciona actualiza tu pregunta con tu código actualizado para revisarlo

Comment: ¡Funciona! Muchísimas gracias, diegoveloper por tu tiempo.

Comment: no hay problema.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, diegoveloper, te amplío info. He simplificado el código para hacerlo lo más claro posible.
Básicamente, lo que hago es construir una cadena y enviarla vía GET a mi servidor. Con esa cadena, el servidor hace una serie de consultas a una BBDD Mysql y devuelve un valor de <0> si va todo bien o <1>, <2> si hay alguna incidencia. En pruebas realizadas desde el navegador Firefox, estas consultas llevan un par de segundos como mucho, antes de responder, pero no son inmediatas. 
El código:

```
    package xxx.httpget004;

import ...


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView lblMensajes;
    private Button btnGet;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //textview para ver los mensajes
        final TextView lblMensajes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMensajes);

        //botón
        final Button btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGet);

        //imageview para mostrar un punto verde o rojo según la respuesta del servidor
        final ImageView ivOk = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivOk);


        ivOk.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //no muestro imagen


        btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                int icanal = 0;


                    codigo = hazYManda(icanal);

                    //tratamiento codigo recibido
                    if (codigo == null) {//si el código recibido es null

                        //imagen de un triangulo amarillo
                        ivOk.setImageResource(R.drawable.alert);
                        //muestro la imagen
                        ivOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        lblMensajes.setText("Sin respuesta del servidor\nIntentelo de nuevo");
                    } else {
                        //si recibo <0> es que ha ido todo bien
                        if (codigo.contains("<0>")){
                            ivOk.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
                            lblMensajes.setText("Todo correcto");
                        }
                        else {
                            //si no es <0> ha habido alguna incidencia
                            //imagen de un punto rojo
                            ivOk.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel);
                            lblMensajes.setText("Ha habido alguna incidencia");
                        }

                        ivOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                        

                    }


                    //me espero 5 segundos para que no se pulse el botón rápidamente (desactivo el botón durante 5 s)
                    final long esperaTime = 5000L; //se espera 5s
                    btnGet.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            lblMensajes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099CC"));
                            lblMensajes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                            btnGet.setEnabled(true);
                            lblMensajes.setText("Pulsa el botón");

                            //ivNo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            ivOk.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            //ivAlerta.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, esperaTime);

                }           


            }
        });




    }


    public String hazYManda(int ipu) {
        //Esta función construye una cadena y con ella hace un GET a mi servidor.

        //Este es un ejemplo simplificado. Con la cadena recibida vía GET, el servidor
        //hace unas cuantas consultas a una base de datos MySQL y según el resultado de esas consultas
        //devuelve una cadena que es "<0>" si va todo bien o, en caso contrario, <1> o <2> según la incidencia

        //construyo la cadena ABCD:1
        String scadena = "ABCD:";
        scadena += Integer.toString(ipu);

        //construyo la cadena para hacer GET
        String xurl = "http://miservidor/fichero.php?key=" + scadena;

        String sj = hacerGet(xurl); //aquí sj recibiría la respuesta del servidor
        //que puede ser null si no responde, <0> si va todo bien o <1> si hay fallo.
        //Es importante esperarse a la respuesta del servidor

        return sj;

    }




    public String hacerGet(String url) {
        //final TextView lblMensajes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMensajes);

        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.

        scode = null;

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if (response == "") scode = "Sin respuesta";
                        else scode = response;
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //scode = "Error";
                //errServidor = error.getMessage();
                scode = error.getMessage();
            }

        });


        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 1, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(stringRequest);



        return scode;
    }





}
```

Espero ser lo más claro posible.
En fín, a ver si qué podemos hacer.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: dame unos minutos y te doy la solución